# SSL/wallet error trying to access Oracle DB from SSRS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, odac

I'm trying to access a third party Oracle database from SQL Server Reporting Services.  I had it working on previous versions of SQL Server and Oracle ODAC, but it's been several years. I'm now being forced into an upgrade, and when I try to create the data source in SSRS, I get the following error:

- **Network Transport: SSL failure in parsing wallet location**

I created an ODBC connection and am able to successfully test the connection, so I know all of the settings in tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora are correct.  I know SSRS is looking at the correct files because I can get a different error by changing the connect identifier to something made up.  The wallet is in a sub-directory of the tnsnames file.  I have tried placing the wallet location in both files, but no combination seems to work.

tnsnames.ora

```
<Connect Identifier> = 
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = <host>)(PORT = <port>)))
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = <SID>)(SERVER = DEDICATED))
  (SECURITY = (MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY = D:\Oracle\wallet))
  )
```

sqlnet.ora

```
WALLET_LOCATION= (SOURCE=
  (METHOD=file)
  (METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=D:\Oracle\wallet)))
```

Current configuration

- Windows Server 2016
- Microsoft SQL Server 2016
- 64-bit ODAC 12.2c

Comment: whose directory is D:\Oracle\wallet - the 3rd party's or your SQL Server's ?

Comment: My server--same as where everything else is installed.

Comment: Are you defining your data source as Oracle or as ODBC? Can you try either?

Comment: I'm trying to go with the Oracle data source.  I was only testing the ODBC because that's our legacy way of accessing the database (through Access).  Looks like ODBC would work--I would have thought that going through the native Oracle connection would be preferable, but if it works it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to AWS RDS DB - TCPS: Invalid SSL Wallet (Magic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220070/oracle-manageddataaccess-to-aws-rds-db-tcps-invalid-ssl-wallet-magic)

Answer (score 0):

The take away to solving this problem is each time you change the SQLORA.NET file you have to restart the SRSS Windows Service.